# Nest JS opentelemetry README configuration is causing Typescript errors

Tags: typescript, nestjs, open-telemetry

Im trying to enable opentelemetry in a nest app. The recommended nestjs-otel README config is failing with type errors. metricExporter and  metricInterval don't exist on the NodeSDKInterface so how is the README configuration possible? If its a case of outdated docs, then how/were do we set the metricExporter and internval? github issue raised here. https://github.com/pragmaticivan/nestjs-otel/issues/395. Thanks for any guidance.

source: https://github.com/pragmaticivan/nestjs-otel

Copied here:

NodeSJConfiguration interface does not have metricExporter and metricInterval properties causing TS errors using the README config. Im using latest nest-otel and latest versions of. all dependencies.

Im using the following combination of packages

```
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "nestjs-otel": "^5.0.0",
    "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.4.0",
    "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.36.3",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger": "^1.9.1",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-prometheus": "^0.35.1",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.35.1",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "^1.9.1",
```

with the following config copied from the README (note I aded a jaeger trace exporter)

```
const otelSDK = new NodeSDK({
    metricExporter: new PrometheusExporter(),
    metricInterval: 1000,
    traceExporter: new JaegerExporter(),
    spanProcessor: new BatchSpanProcessor(new JaegerExporter()),
    contextManager: new AsyncLocalStorageContextManager(),
    textMapPropagator: new CompositePropagator({
        propagators: [
            new JaegerPropagator(),
            new W3CTraceContextPropagator(),
            new W3CBaggagePropagator(),
            new B3Propagator(),
            new B3Propagator({
                injectEncoding: B3InjectEncoding.MULTI_HEADER,
            }),
        ],
    }),
    instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
});
```

Neither metricExporter nor metricInterval are defined on the NodeSDKConfiguration interface passed to NodeSDK()

```
export interface NodeSDKConfiguration {
    autoDetectResources: boolean;
    contextManager: ContextManager;
    defaultAttributes: SpanAttributes;
    textMapPropagator: TextMapPropagator;
    metricReader: MetricReader;
    views: View[];
    instrumentations: InstrumentationOption[];
    resource: Resource;
    resourceDetectors: Detector[];
    sampler: Sampler;
    serviceName?: string;
    spanProcessor: SpanProcessor;
    traceExporter: SpanExporter;
    spanLimits: SpanLimits;
}
```

Aside from addressing the type incompatibility, how/where do i define my metric parameters if they don't exist on NodeSDKConfiguration? Is that possible with this configuration and package combination?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the README is indeed outdated. However, going over the types of this package, it seems that you need to replace

```
metricExporter: new PrometheusExporter(),
metricInterval: 1000,
```

with

```
metricReader: new PrometheusExporter(),
```